# How to add to map in C++ using emplace?

Tags: c++

I'm getting a compilation error when trying to add entries to a map.

Map declaration:

```
std::map<std::string, Network::ClientConnectionPtr> activeUpstreamConnections_
```

Adding to map (this results in the compilation error show below):

```
 activeDownstreamConnections_.emplace(identifier, clientConnectionPtr);
```

> /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'std::pair,
>   std::unique_ptr
>   ::pair(std::__cxx11::basic_string&, std::unique_ptr&)'

The code below works, but I am not able to use the value of clientConnectionPtr later on:

```
activeDownstreamConnections_.emplace(std::move(identifier), std::move(clientConnectionPtr));
```

I'm essentially trying to keep a map of established TCP connections. How can I fix the compilation error and still be able to re-use the connections that are stored in the map?

Comment: Present your [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that `Network::ClientConnectionPtr` is a `std::unique_ptr`, which is a move-only class modeling unique ownership of a dynamically allocated object.

Therefore you have to `std::move` it inside the map, as it is not-copyable. To use the connections you put in the map, you can simply access them through lookup, or store a raw pointer/reference. E.g.

```
auto res = activeDownstreamConnections_.emplace(
    std::move(identifier), std::move(clientConnectionPtr)); 

auto& connection = res.first->second;
// use `connection`...
```

Comment: I'd probably use the return value of `emplace` rather than doing a lookup right away. But yeah assuming a "weak" pointer is all that's needed in the shown scope, that's a good idea.

Comment: `auto res = activeDownstreamConnections_.emplace(..); auto& connection = res.first->second;`

Answer (score 2):

Unique pointers are, well, unique.

You can't have it in the map and in the outer scope at the same time.

Switch to a shared pointer if you want that.

Comment: No it is right and clear, I don't know who downvoted this answer. My upvote compensates the downvote but I did not upvote for this reason. Good answer -> upvote.

Comment: Did not downvote, but I suspect the last sentence was the culprit. There's no evidence that the OP needs shared ownership, and we all know that `shared_ptr` is often abused.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Granted, I hadn't considered that the requirement to use the resource in the shown scope might only be a short-term usage. Unfortunately the OP did not explain their requirements!